# What are the reasons behind terminating the life cycle of a particular version of Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, migration

After going through Microsoft's page on the [Windows lifecycle fact sheet](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/lifecycle), I am deeply confused regarding the support of the Windows 7 software.

I am presently using Windows 7 64 bit Ultimate Edition on my laptop. I have a dilemma of whether to upgrade my laptop to Windows 8 or buy a new device with the same Windows 7.

I have been using Windows 7 for approximately 2-3 years and now I hear that Microsoft has stopped retailing preinstalled Windows 7. I also heard that support may soon come to an end, as it is a PC so it will not be getting the extended support.

As Windows 8 is completely different when compared to Windows 7 (i.e. in terms of the new user interface of the operating system, which is confusing and difficult to learn as compared to migrating from Windows XP to Windows 7, which was a lot easier).

Will anyone tell me what exactly could be the reason behind the termination of the Windows 7 lifecycle. When compared to Windows XP, it appears to me that Windows 7 is being terminated sooner than imagined.

Comment: there is nothing confusing. Windows has 5 year mainstream and 5 years extended support. Mainstream support end in 2015 and so extedned support runs till 2020. In extended support you only get security updates and no new features like a new DX or IE version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Microsoft have to run end of lifecycles to make sure they are focusing on moving forwards and not keeping old Legacy software using up resources.

You are correct though Windows 7 is only five years old whereas XP lifecycle was closer to 13 years however Microsoft's new strategy will be updates to OS every year so with this in mind expect lifecycles to get even shorter.

However you are slightly mistaken on what this means so on 13 January 2015 Windows 7’s ‘Mainstream Support’ will come to an end. That means no new Service Packs or features will be released. This is wholly different from the end of ‘Extended Support’ which is what happened to Windows XP on 8 April 2014.

Extended Support is the big one to keep in mind this means no more security patches when hackers find holes, no performance improvements, nothing – the OS is effectively dead. Personal computer or corporate computer are no different when it comes to Extended support both will be entitled to the patches that are released during this time and both should be upgraded prior to the end of the Extended Support date.

Hope this is a little clearer!

Comment: To add to your generally correct answer, doing the math, Windows 7 will have an expected life-cycle of 11 years. Since Windows XP's EOL was pushed back and back again because of the userbase reluctance to change, I will suppose a similar thing will happen to 7.

Comment: Yeah that is true and I think I might have compared Windows XP end of extended lifecycle and Windows 7 end of Mainstream Support so yeah extra 5 years so that brings it up to 10-11 years like you said :)

Comment: @CharlesH Then why the use of Metro UI(tiles display) is difficult to learn

Comment: @user285oo6 It is hard to objectively quantify how "hard" something is to learn, but AFAIK you are not required to use the tiles display to go about your life. At any rate, Microsoft is just responding to a current trend regarding touch-enabled devices. Since the "normal" interface has been in widespread use since the late 80's, it seems logic that more people are accustomed to window-like interfaces.

Comment: @user285oo6 Yeah I agree with Doktoro its more a preference rather a skill level.. However have a look at Windows 9 previews leaking around the web and it is looking good.. Like a nice mix between Windows 8.1 Metro and Windows 7 start menu :)

Comment: @Dok i thought they would terminate only for the sake of Security measures.

Comment: @CharlesH with win 9 it seems they are trying to bridge the gap between the OS of different platforms.(i.e.Mobile,desktop,gaming consoles etc)